# Overriding global variables inside an imported module only locally?

Tags: css, sass

I have main.scss file (in the context of CSS Paged Media ) containing

```
$margin-left 2cm;

@page {
   size: a4;
   margin-left: $margin-left;
}

@import "_toc";

....
```

and a _toc.scss containing

```
$margin-left 4cm;

@page toc {
     margin-left: $margin-left;
}
```

The default margin-left for all pages should be 2cm but on a particular page (table of contents) I need 4 cm

The reassignment of $margin-left in _toc.scss modifies the value of the global variable.

Is there some mechanism for overriding global variables locally (only inside the _toc.scss file) other than using a dedicated variable specific to _toc.scss?

Comment: Are you missing some colons after the var names? `$margin-left: 2cm`

Comment: ..does not matter and unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the same value of the variable and call it like
`margin-left: $margin-left + 2;` which will give the same result you want without changing the value of variable. And if you still want to change the value you can define new value inside the `@page toc` which will not change global value

Comment: Not an option since the specialized value is not based on a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the overriding variable inside the selector block:

```
@page toc {
    $margin-left: 4cm;
    margin-left: $margin-left;
}
```

Demo: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/456110c2fa766d4250ecbb9d840cf38f

Comment: Possibly an option but unlikely a good solution. For the sake of readabilty: var decls should be place at the top of a file and not somewhere inside the template...so your advice does not make much sense.

Comment: Seems to be logical to me, defining variables within the scope that they are used. Same as in JavaScript.

Comment: As said: not an option for readability reasons. You want variable to be defined upfront and not somewhere...

Comment: In which case maybe you could define a mixin at the top of the file called vars and the include it in the selector block.

Comment: Perhaps not as bad as the other solutions :-)